# My updated gfortran compiler is requiring libraries that are older than those that my previous version of gfortran required - how do I fix this?

Tags: gcc, gfortran, gcc4.7

I updated the version of gfortran from GNU Fortran (GCC) 4.8.5 to version 6.3.0 in order to fix an issue with an ieee_arithmetic problem.  When I did, I found that there was a whole set of new problems.  The new compiler is requiring older libraries, for instance while the version gfortran 4.8.5 used libgmp.so.10, the gfortran 6.3.0 wants libgmp.so.3.  Up to now we have been able to fix this by making a link that points from the name of the old library to the new library.  While this has worked thus far, the list of libraries is getting long,  and this is obviously not ideal.  Is this a problem with the way that the compiler was installed?  Is there a compiler flag that I am not recognizing that will fix this issue? Thanks for any help!

Comment: 6.3.0 is still more than ancient. And the compiler requiring *older* libraries sounds unlikely – is it maybe your build system reacting negatively to your updated compiler and thinks its an even more outdated system?

Comment: OK, thanks, I don't find that surprising.   It is difficult to get new versions of anything here.  Are you recommending that we update gfortran then?  Do you recommend a version that is stable, but new enough?

Comment: every release of GCC is stable, otherwise they wouldn't call it a release. "I don't get new versions of anything here": well, you do seem to have access to the internet, so get *any* Linux of the last 5 years, and you'll get a significantly more modern version of GCC automatically; that will still be able to build at the very least static libraries for any old system. It's really hard to guess what your limitations are or where they come from.

Comment: Be aware that you can compile GCC yourself even without any root or admin account. I did it many times even on old computers with Redhat where the default compiler was 4.4. GCC includes scripts that download all prerequisities.

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful.  Will the scripts install all of the necessary libraries?  I am beginning to believe that the sysadmin that installed the "new" gcc somehow did it without installing the new libraries, so it seems to be defaulting to very old libraries that are older than what my previous version of gcc used.